# What is the difference between Get-Random and random

Tags: powershell

While experimenting with a small script, it suddenly became much slower. I realized that I had substituted `random` for `get-random`, assuming it was an alias.

Compare the following outputs:

```
measure-command { (0..1000) | % { get-random } }
...
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 86
...
```

vs

```
measure-command { (0..1000) | % { random } }
...
Seconds           : 44
Milliseconds      : 192
...
```

It appears that `random` is ~50x slower than `get-random`. It appears that `random` is **not** an alias of `get-random`, even though it seems to the same parameters. `get-alias random` and `get-command random` both return an error that `random` cannot be not found.

**TL;DR**

`random` is not `get-random`, what is it?

Comment: `random` need more time to command lookup, but it resolved to `get-random` in the end.

Comment: @PetSerAl Why doesn't it show up as an alias on the `get-random` documentation page, or by a `get-alias` command, or even a `get-command`?

Comment: Because it is not alias. It is special PowerShell feature. If `CommanName` can not be resolved as command, then PowerShell will try to resolve it as `Get-CommandName` command.

Comment: @PetSerAl Well, that answers my question. If you'll post that an answer with a link to the appropriate documentation, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I can not link you to documentation, and I does not even remember blog post where I read about that, but you can invoke this command to see command discovery events: `Trace-Command Command* {random} -PSHost`.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing, especially if random is essentially an alias for get-random. It is 178x! slower on my machine. It must be that the get-random -> random substitution happens after all of the Path has been searched for .EXEs/.BAT/etc. Which would explain the variation in slowdown across machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`random` *is* `Get-Random`

When PowerShell cannot resolve a 1-word command to a function/alias/executable, it acts as if the `Get` verb is implied.

This works for any other `Get-*` cmdlet as well. Try some of these in `powershell.exe`:

```
item .
childitem $env:USERPROFILE
help random
content $env:SystemRoot\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

---

I'm not actually sure this is mentioned in the help files, but it has been the case since PowerShell version 1.0, as described in the 2006 book ["Monad (AKA. PowerShell): Introducing the MSH Command Shell and Language"](https://books.google.com/books?id=naabAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PR1&pg=PA6):

> All nouns have a default verb, `get`, which is assumed if no verb is
>   given. In other words, the command `process` will behave in exactly
>   the same manner as `get-process`

Comment: Actually `help`, in PS 3.0 & PS 2.0, is defined as a function, essentially `get-help|more`. That's why help pages (in a console session) and `get-help` doesn't.